# Why does Movies & TV prevent guests from posting?

Tags: support, unregistered-users

Movies & TV, unlike most Stack Exchange sites, prevents unregistered users from posting questions or answers. Why so?

---

When I try to post a answer for this [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11030/how-much-of-the-video-compilation-made-for-lillys-memorial-was-actually-amanda) anonymously. It doesn't allow me to do it.

[image]

---

I tried to post a question at that Stack Exchange, it's asking me to create an account there:

[image]

Comment: There are several other sites that prevent anonymous questions, answers, or probably even both. So I edited to fix that inaccuracy.

Comment: Could be spam. Seems a natural fit for streaming spammers